# Why is the iOS 11: self.performSegue() not working?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios11, xcode9

I started the migration to Xcode 9 & iOS 11 build today.

In my storybased app, the following code:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Const.UI.Segue.showIntro, sender: self)
```

runs fine in all previous iOS (just verified with iOS 10.3, 10.0, 9.0) but does not run in iOS 11.

Additional code:

```
private func handleSuccessfulLogin() {
    self.log.info("Logged In")
    DispatchQueue.main.async(){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Const.UI.Segue.showIntro, sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("starting segue " + segue.identifier!)
}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    print("should perform segue")
    return true
}
```

printout (iOS 11):

```
> Logged In
> starting segue showIntroSegue
```

Expected result: **new controller pushed**

Actual result iOS 11: **nothing at all happens**

Any ideas what the reason might be?

The function `handleSuccessfulLogin()` is called after a successful login with `AWSCognito / AWSFacebookSignInProvider`, a facebook login. On iOS there is a new popup `continue with facebook` which I suspect to be the reason, but I got no way to verify it.. On the 2nd call this popup does not appear (as facebook already is authorized), and then the segue triggers correctly.

Note, I also tried this snippet, same result.

```
OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        [weak self] in
        self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: Const.UI.Segue.showIntro, sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: Remove the segue from your Storyboard and add it again.

Comment: @RashwanL no change sadly

Comment: Does that segue identifier evaluate to what you expect?

Comment: @JackDaw added some additional code. Yes, the const evaulates to "showIntroSegue" which is correctly logged `prepareForSegue` - also note that on all other iOS except 11 it works fine. Issue present on device & simulator.

Comment: I'd put some logs in the destination VC init, viewDidLoad, etc.

Comment: Is the segue custom? Has it a value for `segue.destinationController`?

Comment: i realized that on the 2nd call it works. The segue is triggered automatically after a sucessful AWSCognito / Facebook login. First time, even though the segue is triggered (preparesegue is logged out), the destination viewcontroller is not shown. On the 2nd click (which does not reopen FB again) it does work. Not sure what this means. maybe there is some reimainder of the FB framework still 'in the way' :/

Comment: @Larme yes, destination is there & correct

Comment: Is `handleSuccessfulLogin` called on main thread? When if fails, you may want to have a look at the view hierarchy: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2 Maybe it's hidden for unknown reason, or the FB is causing issue...

Comment: @Larme yes, mainthread with dispatch. it's not hidden and visible in hierarchy. so strange :/

Comment: Are you logging in through a web view with Facebook? And does the pop up show after you have successfully logged in only? Or is the “continue with Facebook” prompt shown when trying to log in?

Comment: I have been able to solve the problem, see my answer.

Comment: in the view-lifecycle, exactly _when_ do you try to invoke the `func handleSuccessfulLogin()` method? has your current view been loaded and presented already _when_ this method is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to be at a completely different place (as so often).
The reason was that I had a logic in place in `applicationDidBecomeActive` that was replacing the current storyboard (bad approach!) - the additional popup from the FB Kit led to a recreation of my container view controller. Thus i had `self.navigationController == nil` during the call to perform the segue.

Comment: :- I am also facing similar issue in my app.PushNavigation is not working in iOS11. If you had some logic in applicationDidBecomeActive. Then why was it working fine in iOS 10 ??

Comment: @Developer because only iOS 11 adds an additional alert when using Facebook Login. This alert was triggering an additional 'appliationDidBecomeActive', so i ended up with 2 viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 0):

According to discussions, `viewDidLoad` is inappropriate to place to call perform segue, but there are plenty of user cases where wanting to trigger a segue before the view appears, special case as it has been working previous to `X9`, as the segue seem to trigger when either having the view controller in a navigation controller or dispatching to main (in `viewDidLoad`), which should be already on the main thread when presenting a loaded view.

This I would consider a bug, rather than an undocumented feature.

Comment: Considering the notion of reducing application and class states needing to perform in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear demands class scoped state to evaluate since viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear are called everytime the view appears to prevent the segue being called every time, which in turn brings the notion of it being a bug rather than a safety feature.